# Bash: Remove lines from text file starting after a matched row? (AppleScript ok)

Tags: applescript, command-line, bash, unix, text

I have these horribly formatted text files that look like this:

```
Heading
FIELD_DELIM TABS
VIDEO_FORMAT    1080
FILM_FORMAT 35mm, 4 perf
AUDIO_FORMAT    48khz
FPS 24

Column
Name    Tape    Start   Source File End Tc in   Tracks  

Data
WTF0567_comp_v446.15068     00:00:41:16 WTF0567_comp_v446.15068.mov 00:00:43:19 04:02:37:21 V   
OMG5120_fx_v001     00:00:42:11 OMG5120_fx_v001.mov 00:00:43:20 02:14:42:17 V   
NAW0366_anim_v032       00:00:41:16 GTP0170_MPC_comp_v0219.mov  00:00:44:21 01:02:20:05 V
```

Yes, there is an empty horizontal tab at the end of some rows, but not others. There is also an empty line at the bottom, which I don't know how to show here in `code` formatting.

REQUEST: I need to remove every line under the line that starts with "Data" from these text files. I'd like to do this as bash code, but an AppleScript solution should work as well. Bonus points if we can retain that last empty line.

Comment: The challenge with sed is that most examples you find on the Internet are using GNU sed, which has way more functionality than the BSD sed which is part of macOS. The easiest workaround for this is actually to install GNU sed via Homebrew. In your case, `sed '/^Data/,$d'` probably (I don't have a Mac nearby right now to verify) would have worked (delete everything from Data til the end of the input ($)). But the solution in the answer for sure is better because it doesn't even read anything from the input file after finding the match.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your description of what you're trying to do. Do you want to delete just a single line after the "Data" line (i.e. just the line that starts "WTF0567..."), or *every* line after it ("WTF0567...", "OMG5120...", and "NAW0366..."), or the "Data" line *and* the one after it, or... BTW, the reason `/Data/,1d` doesn't work is that it's trying to delete a region *starting* with the "Data" line and *ending* with line #1 (i.e. the first line in the file), and they aren't in that order.

Comment: I need to remove every line under the line that starts with "Data" from these text files. Meaning, I need to keep the `Data` line, but delete everything below it. My initial idea was to use regex to find the `Data` line, then everything below it, and replace it with just a `Data\n` basically. But I'm new to `sed` and can't figure out how to write it.

Comment: @nohillside Oh really? They made different versions of `sed`? That's helpful. haha! Seeing this, and the response below. I'm now thinking a better approach may be for me to learn `awk` instead. I plan to share this script with friends who should never ever open Terminal, if you catch my drift.

Comment: The `sed` command used in the answer will work both for BSD and GNU sed (in general, things which work in BSD sed will work in the GNU version, but not the other way around).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your data is in a file called `input`, and that `input` is a unix text file (`\n` for line-endings, not `\r` (traditional Mac OS) nor those `\r\n` (Internet linefeeds)):

```
$ cat input
Heading
FIELD_DELIM TABS
VIDEO_FORMAT    1080
FILM_FORMAT 35mm, 4 perf
AUDIO_FORMAT    48khz
FPS 24

Column
Name    Tape    Start   Source File End Tc in   Tracks

Data
WTF0567_comp_v446.15068     00:00:41:16 WTF0567_comp_v446.15068.mov 00:00:43:19 04:02:37:21 V
OMG5120_fx_v001     00:00:42:11 OMG5120_fx_v001.mov 00:00:43:20 02:14:42:17 V
NAW0366_anim_v032       00:00:41:16 GTP0170_MPC_comp_v0219.mov  00:00:44:21 01:02:20:05 V
```

the `sed` program can print lines (`p`) but will quit (`q`) upon finding a line that begins with `Data`. Keystrokes were pretty expensive back in the 300 baud modem days, therefore the one-letter commands.

```
$ sed -n '/^Data/q;p' input
Heading
FIELD_DELIM TABS
VIDEO_FORMAT    1080
FILM_FORMAT 35mm, 4 perf
AUDIO_FORMAT    48khz
FPS 24

Column
Name    Tape    Start   Source File End Tc in   Tracks
```

To quit "after" the `Data` line one merely needs to fiddle with the logic a little, or to add a `Data` line back in again using a subshell to group output with the `sed` command:

```
sed '/^Data/q' input
( sed -n '/^Data/q;p' input; printf "Data\n" )
```

Or, you can use `awk`, which here is pretty much the same as the `sed` only more verbose:

```
$ awk '/^Data/{exit} {print}' input
Heading
FIELD_DELIM TABS
VIDEO_FORMAT    1080
FILM_FORMAT 35mm, 4 perf
AUDIO_FORMAT    48khz
FPS 24

Column
Name    Tape    Start   Source File End Tc in   Tracks
```

`awk` probably makes it easier to force the inclusion of your last line is blank requirement (`sed` can do this but it's more annoying, or not, depending on the exact version of `sed` involved):

```
awk '/^Data/{print "this line left blank";exit} {print}'
awk '/^Data/{print "";exit} {print}'
awk '/^Data/{print;exit} {print}' input
```

You could also do this in `bash` but `bash` is really not a good choice for this compared to `sed` or `awk` or really just about anything else, and would be a lot slower. But, since you asked...

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do [[ $line = Data* ]] && break; printf '%s\n' "$line"; done < input
```

See what I mean about `bash`? Yikes.

(`sed` and `awk` are not `bash` commands; `bash` (1989) did not exist when `sed` was written (1974). `bash` can run unix commands, but so can any other unix shell, e.g. `sh`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `fish`, *etc.*, and so can any unix program that makes a suitable `exec(3)` call... unless you mean bash in some sort of "this is unix! I know unix!" sense (Jurrasic Park, 1993), like how to "google" means to search, maybe not using anything made by Google. Only one of the above commands was actually run under `bash`, for example.)

Comment: Looking at this again, @thrig... with the `sed` solution you gave, how would I tell it to stop printing after the `Data` line, instead of before? Keep in mind, the line below the `Data` line will always start with something different. Also, this really helps, thank you. I was thinking about this in a different way.

Comment: Lastly, I just tried all those solutions out, and none of them gave me the results you got. I'm on a Mac if that matters. The `sed` one gave me the exact opposite of what you got; it gave me all the lines I didn't want, instead of the ones I did. And when I tried to push the output to a `input1.txt` file, it didn't do anything... I just ended up with a copy of the file I started with. Same for `awk` except all versions of it just spit out the same file I started with. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Here is an applescript solution. It reads the text document, finds the offset of the linefeed and truncates at that point, making the linefeed the last character of the document.

```
tell application "Finder" to set srcFile to choose file

-- read file and locate last desirable character position
set rFile to read srcFile
set dataOffset to (offset of "Data" & linefeed in rFile) + 4 -- will be linefeed
--> 171

-- end file at last desirable character
set eof of srcFile to dataOffset

read srcFile -- view results
```

Answer (score 1):

As for taking a shell-based route… these three approaches search for a range that reaches from the beginning of the document through to the 'Data' line and then prints that while ignoring any text thereafter.

The first two will work presuming that the first line begins with 'Heading'. It is probable that should you discover a way to specify the document's first character or word then you could implement that instead. By default, they all seem to leave an empty line at the document's end.

First, awk:

```
% awk '/^Heading/,/Data$/' blue.txt > green.txt
```

Then, perl:

```
% perl -ne 'print if /Heading/../Data$/' blue.txt > red.txt
```

Finally, sed:

```
% sed -n '1,/Data/ p' blue.txt > yellow.txt
```

Note that the sed command specifies line 1 rather than any particular text, ergo it will work even when your document begins with some other text. I should add that I'm using the default sed that comes with Sierra. There doesn't seem to be a way to get its version but it's in '/usr/bin/' so it's likely original.